# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module. When using RequireJS in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

**Background**

`RequireJS` is a dependancy for another package I want to use in a `Visualforce` page. I have uploaded `RequireJS` as a `static resource`.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">

    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.require }" />

</apex:page>
```

But when I run the above code, I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(k)...

**Questions**

1. is it possible to use `RequireJS` in a visualforce page?
2. if yes, what am I doing wrong?
3. if yes, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to use RequireJS in a visualforce page?

Yes.

> if yes, what am I doing wrong?

You have to delay loading the script until the page is ready.

> if yes, how do I fix it?

Specify the appropriate attribute:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.require }" loadOnReady="true" />
```

Note that the only way I could get this to work is to also load all future scripts using this same syntax. Do not use script tags or you may get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Is it possible to get `RequireJS` to work in a Lightning component?

Comment: @Robs requireJS doesn't seem to be Lightning-compatible out of the box, but it could be patched? I really don't see any point, though, since we have ltng:require.

Comment: Does `ltng:require` work as a AMD loader, like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/master/browser-amd-editor/index.html)?

Comment: @Robs Strictly speaking, no. But you can [browserify](http://browserify.org/) the code and upload the results. These should be Lightning-compatible.